# TPT12109: Export Operator does not support JSON column.Is there a way to export results involving json column other than bteq export?

Tags: json, teradata

I have a table having 2 million records. I am trying to dump the contents of the table in  json format. This issue is that the TPT export does not allow JSON columns and BTEQ export would take a lot of time to do this export. Is there any way to handle this export in a more optimized way.

Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing. Load the json formatted rows in another teradata table.
Keep that table column as varchar and then do a tptexport of that column/table. 
It should work.

```
INSERT INTO test (col1,col2...,jsn_obj)
SELECT col1,col2,..
JSON_Compose(<. columns you want to inlcude in your json file)
FROM <schemaname>.<tablename>
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON values are not too large, you could potentially CAST them in your SELECT as `VARCHAR(64000) CHARACTER SET LATIN`, or `VARCHAR(32000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE` if you have non-LATIN characters, and export them in-line.

Otherwise each JSON object has to be transferred DEFERRED BY NAME where each object is stored in a separate file and the corresponding filename stored in the output row. In that case you would need to use BTEQ, or TPT SQL Selector operator - or write your own application.

Comment: I have 70 mill rows , so the above option will not be feasible.